# A synonym for interpolation model?

Tags: terminology, interpretation

I interpolated a surface of x y and z. so for each x and y there is z.
I called it a proxy model but my supervisor said i am far from that and I need to find a different word to describe my surface model of interpolation.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I have no idea what a *surface model of interpolation* is supposed to mean, even after googling that phrase. We *might* be able to help here if OP would explain exactly what he means (using as many words as necessary), but my guess is this is an Off Topic question about "domain-specific terminology" in the context of 3D modelling / printing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but your supervisor is probably unhappy with your using the term **model** to because that word has a [specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model) in mathematics that implies a level of complexity that is far beyond a mere interpolation of points.

The formal term for an interpolation across two variables is a [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) or [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation), depending on which interpolation method you're using.  Or you could just call it an "interpolated surface" if you want to keep things simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, He was totally against the word proxy not against the word model but I will go with the interpolated surface

Comment: Well, "proxy" means "something that acts as a substitute," so unless you're using this interpolation as a substitute for something else (maybe a first-principles calculation for example), then I think I agree with your supervisor.